# kotlin adding pair to map when value is a list

Tags: dictionary, kotlin

I know this is basic but can I do this in a shorter way:

```
val ss = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>()
if(ss["new_key"] != null){
    ss["new_key"]!!.add("NEW")
}
else{
    ss["new_key"] = mutableListOf("OLD")
}
```

This basically checks if the key exists in the map

if it does an element is appended to the list(value) otherwise a new key-value pair is created

Can't I create a new key on the go? like this:

```
ss["new_key"].add("OLD")
ss["new_key"].add("NEW")
```

Comment: That's not possible out of the box. You could override the add() method of the Map i guess. But that's some lousy workaround. Please don't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have at least 2 options:

- use `computeIfAbsent`:

  ```
  ss.computeIfAbsent("new_key") { mutableListOf() } += "NEW"
  ```
- use `getOrPut`:

  ```
  ss.getOrPut("new_key", ::mutableListOf) += "NEW"
  ```

Comment: Im getting `variable expected` error on this code. Am I missing something?

Comment: @miradham You may have used `List` type argument in `mutableMapOf<String, List<String>>()` rather than `MutableList` - `mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>()`.